502 Bad Gateway Error after Switching from NodePort to Ingress for Kasten K10 Dashboard
I am trying to access the Kasten K10 dashboard (kasten-io gateway service) using Ingress after initially using NodePort, which worked fine. However, after configuring Ingress, I am encountering a 502 Bad Gateway error when trying to access the service externally.
Setup Details:

NodePort Configuration (Working): I initially used a NodePort for the Kasten K10 gateway service and was able to access the dashboard at http://172.22.3.135:31793/k10/.

Ingress Configuration (Error 502): After switching to Ingress, I configured the following Ingress resource to route traffic to the gateway service:


apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kasten-ingress
  namespace: kasten-io
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /k10/
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: gateway
              port:
                number: 80

This configuration should route traffic to the gateway service, which listens on port 80 and forwards traffic to targetPort: 8000.

Error Encountered: After applying the Ingress configuration, I attempted to access the service via http://172.22.3.200/k10/, but I received a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Below is the error log from the NGINX Ingress controller:
2024/12/26 08:32:41 [error] 163#163: *28700 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.22.3.135, server: _, request: "GET /k10/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.36.188:8000/k10/", host: "172.22.3.200"

4.Current Configuration:

Gateway Service: The gateway service is of type NodePort, with targetPort: 8000.

kubectl get svc gateway -n kasten-io


Ingress Resource: The Ingress controller has the external IP 172.22.3.200.

kubectl get ingress -n kasten-io

The logs indicate that the Ingress controller is unable to reach the gateway service at 192.168.36.188:8000, resulting in the 502 Bad Gateway error.
Questions:

Is there a misconfiguration in the Ingress resource?
How can I ensure that the Ingress controller properly forwards traffic to the gateway service on port 8000?

